# Angle in a triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, geometry

[image]

The question I'm dealing with here deals with mechanics but my specific question concerns the geometry of the shapes involved (I didn't post this to the math stack exchange because it's more likely that there are people familiar with this question here). I consulted the answers and it says that the bottom angle of the isosceles triangle has an angle of 2θ and I'm not sure why. I've looked the problem and can't seem to find any reason that this should be the case but I'm sure I'm being dense

Comment: Hi James and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: I don't need help with the question, I already have the answer. I just need an explanation of a certain result that was explained in the answer

Comment: Your question is about geometry, not physics. You are not asking about a force, you are asking about an angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ignore the crapyness of my drawing and combine it with the information on your drawing, you should realise that the angles I called a and b are both $\theta$ due to symmetrie. That implies that the angle I called c is 180°-2$\theta$.

If you now focus your attention to the quadrangle consisting of c, the two intersects between the main triangle and triange abc plus the lowest point of the main triangle, you see that that last angle must be 2$\theta$, as the sum of the 4 angles (180-2$\theta$+90+90+?) should be 360°

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Completely forgot about the tangent and radius meeting at a 90 degree angle